# How do conformal maps affect curvature?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature, conformal-geometry, hypersurfaces

Let $(\overline{M}^{n+1}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a riemannian manifold with riemannian connection $\overline{\nabla}$ and consider $M^n \subset \overline{M}$ an orientable hypersurface with unit normal vector field $\nu: M \to T \overline{M}$. Given a conformal diffeomorphism $f: \overline{M} \to \overline{M}$ say, with conformal factor $\mu^2 \in C^{\infty}(\overline{M}, \mathbb{R}_+)$, i.e.,

\begin{align*}
\langle Df(p) \cdot v_1, Df(p) \cdot v_2\rangle = \mu^2(p) \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle, \quad \forall p \in \overline{M}, \, \forall v_1, v_2 \in T_p \overline{M},
\end{align*}
how can we relate the principal curvatures of $M$ at a point $p$ with those of $f(M)$ at the point $f(p)?$